# how do I copy data from one cell to another?

Tags: microsoft-access

I am working on an expense report that on the main table is listed as "Lodging" in a column. This will have a currency in it for how much was spent. How do I copy the data in that cell to another table called "lodging" that will list all the trips I have with a "Charter ID" and "Amount”? I’d like to copy the "charter id" and "amount " to another table automatically.